# Detect if the user wanted to open link in new window or tab (Mac and Windows)

Tags: jquery, browser, onclick

I have a link that, in order to optimize the page response/traffic, I handle its `click` event with a javascript `click` handler. On `click`, I only load some part of the page. But the link's URL is correct and opening it in a standalone tab would open the page correctly.

But when the user presses CMD-Click on the link (to open the link in new tab), the `click` handler runs and the page is **NOT** opened in new tab. Basically I disabled the CMD-Click (open in new tab) functionality. How can I detect this in code in order to make CMD-Click work as expected. (In Windows CMD is replaced by Ctrl.)?

```
$(".link").on("click", function(event) {

    if (/* TODO: how to detect if the user CMD/Ctrl-clicked the link? */) {
        return true;
    }

    // ... load only necessary things for normal clicks
})
```

Do I have to write OS/browser specific code to solve the `TODO` above? (I use jQuery)

Comment: What would you do to Right mouse button/open in new tab? Mouse scroll click? Shift + click?

Comment: @YuryTarabanko: `event.which` can handle the middle-click.  Right-clicking and selecting open in new tab won't fire the event handler in the first place.

Comment: @josh3736 I believe there is a better way to tell if you need to load the entire page. Maybe `X-Requested-With` header will do the trick

Comment: may this help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10660360/command-click-doesnt-open-a-new-tab-but-middle-click-does

Comment: There are many keys that change the default behavior, not just `ctrl`. You're better off using something like [`filter-altered-clicks`](https://github.com/bfred-it/filter-altered-clicks) to handle it for you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check the `event`'s `ctrlKey`, `shiftKey`, and `metaKey` properties.  These tell you if the user was holding control, shift, or command respectively.  Also check that `which` is not `2`, which means the user middle-clicked the link.

```
$(".link").on("click", function(event) {

    if (event.ctrlKey || event.shiftKey || event.metaKey || event.which == 2) {
        return true;
    }

    // ... load only necessary things for normal clicks
});
```